# Return two responses in Flask/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a Flask/JavaScript application wherein I take a form's inputs and pass them to a Flask app to retrieve distance information from the GoogleMaps API and subsequently return the resulting JSON to JavaScript.This works fine for a single instance of an origin/destination.

I want to receive two origin/destination inputs and return both to my JavaScript but cannot figure out how to do that. I'm still learning, but am under the impression I can't simply return two values in a single function so I'm hoping someone can take a look at what I have and tell me what the best approach would be to get the JSON for both back to JavaScript.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # form inputs
        origin = request.form.get('origin')
        destination = request.form.get('destination')
        current_home = request.form.get('current_home')
        future_home = request.form.get('future_home')

        # current traffic conditions set to now
        departure = int(time.time())

        # params we pass to the url
        current_params = {
            'origins': origin,
            'destinations': destination,
            'mode':'driving',
            'units':'imperial',
            'departure_time' : departure,
            'traffic_model':'best_guess',
            'avoid':'tolls'
        }

        future_params = {
            'origins': future_home,
            'destinations': destination,
            'mode':'driving',
            'units':'imperial',
            'departure_time' : departure,
            'traffic_model':'best_guess',
            'avoid':'tolls'
        }

        # api call
        current_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'+ urllib.urlencode(current_params)
        future_url =  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'+ urllib.urlencode(future_params)

        current_response = requests.get(current_url)
        future_response = requests.get(future_url)

        # return json
        return jsonify(current_response.json())
        return jsonify(future_response.json())
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap both values in a dict and then return the dict.

```
payload = {
    "current_response": current_response,
    "future_response": future_response
}

return jsonify(payload)
```